# Condition for existence of a continuous function

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis

Let $  {{x_n}}  $ be a given sequence. Show there exist a continuous function 
$f:[0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such   that $f(1/n)=x_n$,  if and  only if $x_n$ converges  to  a   finite  limit.

Comment: If $f$ is continuous at $x=0$ show that $\lim_{x\to 0}f(x) = \lim_{n\to\infty} f(1/n) = f(0)$.

Comment: I am sorry, I should have said that I proved this direction. f(o) is the limit of x_n, but I want the converse, if the sequence converges, how to show the existence of the continuous function.

Comment: Define $f(1/n) = x_n$ and then draw lines between the points, i.e. define $f(x) = f\left(\frac{1}{n}\right) + \left[f\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)-f\left(\frac{1}{n-1}\right)\right](nx-1)(n-1)$ on the interval $\left[\frac{1}{n},\frac{1}{n-1}\right)$. In the end put $f(0)=\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n$. Now $f$ is defined at every point and is continuous by construction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define $f(1/n)=x_n$ and then join these points with affine linear functions.